# Django POSTing from react app issue, CSFR issue

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies

I am creating a simple Django backend, react frontend app, and am trying to get login working, however I get a couple of errors.
My views function is:

```
# @csrf_exempt
def login_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        print(data, type(data))
        print('username' in data)
    # return JsonResponse({'status':'success'}, safe=False)

        if 'username' not in data or 'password' not in data:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'error'}, safe=False)
        
        # print(data.username)
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        print(username, password)
        user=authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print('yay')
        return JsonResponse({'status':'success'})
```

My settings are:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True
# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
# CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']
# CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']
```

The frontend:

```
const login_link = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/logint'
    const login_link2 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // console.log(event)
        // console.log(event.nativeEvent.target)

        const data = await axios.post(login_link, {username:username, password:password});

        // var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
        // // var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        // var headers = new Headers();
        // var payload = {username:username, password:password}
        // headers.append('X-CSRFToken', csrf);
        // const data = await fetch('/api/upload', {
        //     method: 'POST',
        //     body: payload,
        //     headers: headers,
        //     credentials: 'include'
        // })
        console.log(data)

    }
```

The current error is:

> Forbidden (Origin checking failed - http://localhost:3000 does not match any trusted origins.): /logint

I uncomment the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` and my error becomes:

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /logint

I uncomment `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` and nothing changed. I changed it to None and nothing happened.

I used the `csrf_exempt` and that worked but then when I login and try to do another pull it doesn't save which user.

Switching the API call to the fetch function and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas, I am lost.